# Is there anyway I can load the data to the in-memory instead of using.csv files in effort for unit-testing?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, csv, nunit, effort

Is there anyway I can load the data to the in-memory instead of using.csv files in effort for unit-testing?

Scenario:
I want to load the data to the in-memory to use the Effort framework which creates the fake dbcontext and performs the operation. Instead of using Dataloader and .csv files I need to load the data programatically.

Sample code which works fine with .csv files:

```
        IDataLoader loader = new Effort.DataLoaders.CsvDataLoader("D:\\csv");
        var dataLoader = new CachingDataLoader(loader, false);
        DbConnection connection = Effort.DbConnectionFactory.CreateTransient(dataLoader);
        DbContext mockedDbContext = new NopObjectContext(connection);
        EfRepository<Shelf> _shelEfRepository = new EfRepository<Shelf>(mockedDbContext);
        EfRepository<ProductVariant> _productVariantEfRepository = new EfRepository<ProductVariant>(mockedDbContext);
        EfRepository<Product> _productEfRepository = new EfRepository<Product>(mockedDbContext);
        _shelfService = new ShelfService(_shelEfRepository, _productVariantEfRepository, _productEfRepository);
```

I am just looking for something replacement to load the data instead of loading the data using .csv files

Answer (score 2):

You could create a Transient/Persistent `DbConnection` *without* a DataLoader, use it in your `DbContext`, then programmatically push your generated data into the context.

See: https://tflamichblog.wordpress.com/2012/11/04/factory-methods-in-effort-createtransient-vs-createpersistent